# Android Studio: generating .so files using experimental plugin

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, gradle-experimental

I have a project in AS with native library. I'm trying to use experimental plugin (gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha5) to get .so files (to use it later in System.loadLibrary (). But I can't generate them. And I really can't understand, why?

I've used this [instruction](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental)  to write my build.gradle. Here is it:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.model.application"
model {  
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.camera.simplewebcam"
    minSdkVersion.apiLevel 15
    targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 22

    buildConfigFields {
        create() {
            type "int"
            name "VALUE"
            value "1"
        }
    }

    ndk {
        moduleName "ImageProc"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
    }
}

// Configures source set directory.
sources {
    main {
        jni {
          source {
                srcDir "src/main"
            }
        }
    }
}
productFlavors {
    create("arm") {
        ndk {   
            abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
    }
    create("fat") {           
    }

}
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "lib", include: ['.jar','.so'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+"
}
```

The error I get when try to run the application:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load ImageProc from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.camera.simplewebcam-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.camera.simplewebcam-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]]: findLibrary returned null

Here is my project's structure:
[image]

Here is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := ImageProc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ImageProc.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -ljnigraphics

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here is my Application.mk:

```
# The ARMv7 is significanly faster due to the use of the hardware FPU
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

Where is my error?

Comment: set `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1`

Comment: `targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It seems to me that it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here `targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 22`

> An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If
>   not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion. This
>   attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target
>   version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors
>   to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version.
>   The application is still able to run on older versions (down to
>   minSdkVersion).

**Do**

```
targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
```

and you should use

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
```